# Lower Bound for $\sum_{\{i,j\}\subseteq \partial S \\ (g_i-g_j)^2 \le1}{(g_i-g_j)^2}$

Tags: inequalities

Let $\emptyset \subsetneq S \subsetneq \{1,\cdots,n\}$ be a set with cardinality $s$, and $g\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be a vector such that 
$$\sum_{\{i,j\}\subseteq \{1,\cdots,n\}}{(g_i-g_j)^2} = s(n-s).$$

> **Question.** Is this true?
>   $$\sum_{\{i,j\}\subseteq \partial S \\(g_i-g_j)^2\le1}{(g_i-g_j)^2} \ge \frac{s(n-s)}{n}$$ 
>   where $\partial S$ is the set of all $2$-subsets $\{i,j\}\subseteq \{1,\cdots,n\}$ that exactly one of $i$ or $j$ is in $S$.

Comment: What in the world does this question have to do with either "metric geometry" or "calculus of variations"? Please try to use appropriate tags for your questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Take $n=3$, $S=\{3\}$, $g_3=0$, $g_2=a=1/1000$, $g_1>1$ satisfies $f(g_1)=(g_1-a)^2+g_1^2+a^2=2$, such $g_1$ exists since $f(1)<2$, $f(2)>2$.